# How do I update the mongodb binaries in my nitrous.io box to the 2.4.x versions?

Tags: mongodb, mlab, nitrousio, mongodump, mongorestore

I am taking the "mongodb for node.js" course and trying to import/restore data to my mongolab instance but I keep getting Auth err code 18 errors.

I can connect to any instance I create using the mongo --shell from the nitrous.io box and it works fine. So my connect string and env variables are correct.  If I change the password when logging in to mongo shell it actually gives me the opportunity to put in the correct password. So I know the user authentication is proper.

I am confused as to why I still get Auth err code 18 errors when I try to use the supplied mongodump files.

I have also tried specifying individual .bson files and that gives the same error as well.

I am connecting to mongod version 2.4.6 but mongorestore is only 2.0.4 on the nitrous.io box. I wanted to update to the newer version and see if this is the problem. I have read other posts from other sites where this seemd to break in version 2.2.2. while importing using older versions of the binaries for restore.

it does not appear you(nitrous.io developers) leave a way to update or support mongodb versioning. Do you have a way I could update to mongodb v2.4.6?

also if you could add htop and bmon to your image that would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nitrous has released a package manager dubbed [autoparts](https://github.com/action-io/autoparts) which will allow you to install mongodb 2.4.6.

Autoparts requires you to have a Nitrous box on version "bran" or later. If you are on version "arya" then you will need to download the contents within your box (SCP or Nitrous Mac App), terminate the box, followed by creating a new box in order to upgrade.

Take a look at the README within the Github Repo for instructions on how to use autoparts:

https://github.com/action-io/autoparts

To install/update mongodb to the latest version, run the following command:

```
parts install mongodb
```

After the installation completes, run `mongo` in the console to check the version. You may need to restart the console if it is reporting an older version.

Comment: Thank you. Once I updated mongodb to 2.4.6 I was able to figure out how to get mongorestore to import data and the authentication errors went away